# Is the password "Z" more secure than the password "a"?

Tags: passwords, brute-force

Okay, I guess it's not possible to call one-letter-passwords "secure" - so let's compare `ZZZZZZZZZZ` with `aaaaaaaaaa`.

Both are using the same character pool `[A-z]`, so the number of combinations for a password with ten characters is `56^10 = 144 quadrillion`. According to [HowSecureIsMyPassword](https://howsecureismypassword.net/), this could be brute-forced in about one year.

How are "common" brute force tools (I only know Jack the Ripper) implemented? Do they start with `a`, trying everything up to `z`, and then start again with `A`? Or are they starting with the [most frequently used character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency) `e` to the least used `z`?

Assuming they would: how big would be the difference to calculate `aaaaaaaaaa` vs `ZZZZZZZZZZ`?